# Comparing kafka-node and node-rdkafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I would like to use Kafka with my Node.JS services as a message broker and am debating between the [kafka-node](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node) and [node-rdkafka](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka) libraries.

I started testing kafka-node's capabilities (the library seems to be much more popular) and was able to create a producer, write to Kafka with it, create a consumer, and read from Kafka with it. **However, I noticed that the library does not currently support some Kafka features such as writing timestamps and lz4 compression (features that the Scala driver that I am using supports).**

Has anyone run into these or other setbacks in kafka-node (or node-rdkafka) and decided to use another library due to them?

Comment: We have tested both . producer on rdkafka buffers messages and then sends to kafka based on size and number of meesages  , so it does not give error when  brokers are down . 
consumer in kafka-node has problems with manual commits, which  we required in our case . so we decided  to have producer on kafka-node and consumer on node-rdkafka.

Answer (score 9):

Michal,

I recently completed a comparison of the two libraries.  http://www.tivix.com/blog/nodejs-kafka-producers/.  You will find implementations for both clients.  In summary, I found that rdkafka has lower cpu utilization than node kafka.  Moreover, it is maintained by Blizzard, so I am sure they would be happy to accept any PRs you provided.

Comment: can you suggest how is the performance of kafka with node ? Is it better than kafka with java or python

Comment: Shooting from the hip in this answer a little bit, but the nice thing about using kafka with node is node's async io, so queue activities will not be blocking. I imagine Java has methods available that are similar, however, I'm not sure if that is the case with Python.

Comment: Michal, check your article there are 2 typo "kaka-node" instead of kafka-node. kaka in french means poo. So better to fix this.